# Pandas: Find previous row of matching value

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a column with values from one column, but based on matching another column with the previous value.

Here is my current code:

```
d = {'a':[1,2,3,1,2,3,2,1], 'b':[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df['c'] = df['b'][df['a'] == df['a'].prev()]
```

And my desired output:

```
   a   b    c
0  1  10  NaN
1  2  20  NaN
2  3  30  NaN
3  1  40   10
4  2  50   20
5  3  60   30
6  2  70   50
7  1  80   40
```

...which I'm not getting because `.prev()` is not a real thing.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We can group by `a` column, which by default sorts values and then "attach" [shifted](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) `b` column:

```
In [110]: df['c'] = df.groupby('a')['b'].transform(lambda x: x.shift())

In [111]: df
Out[111]:
   a   b     c
0  1  10   NaN
1  2  20   NaN
2  3  30   NaN
3  1  40  10.0
4  2  50  20.0
5  3  60  30.0
6  2  70  50.0
7  1  80  40.0
```

Or much better option - `using GroupBy.shift()` (thank you [@Mitch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42446006/pandas-find-previous-row-of-matching-value/42446114#comment72035812_42446114))

```
In [114]: df['c'] = df.groupby('a')['b'].shift()

In [115]: df
Out[115]:
   a   b     c
0  1  10   NaN
1  2  20   NaN
2  3  30   NaN
3  1  40  10.0
4  2  50  20.0
5  3  60  30.0
6  2  70  50.0
7  1  80  40.0
```

Comment: This is nice! Is `transform` necessary though? `df.groupby('a')['b'].shift()`

Comment: @Mitch, wow, thank you! I didn't know we can use `GroupBy.shift()`

Comment: @MaxU Every time I find these methods exist on things like GroupBy objects it feels like magic :)

Comment: @pshep123, i've added a short description

Comment: @MaxU - thanks a million for the solution and the explanation!

Comment: @pshep123, glad i could help :-)